# This python code that gets a pass word is not working?

Tags: python

This python code is supposed to ask a user for their password then print out the pass word but it keeps saying ho! It worked for a little while but then I lost the edited code.

```
import sys, os, re, subprocess

def askpass(prompt):
    prompt = prompt.replace('"', "'")

    if 'yes/no' in prompt:
        return "yes"

    script="""
        tell application "Finder"
            activate
            display dialog "%s" \
              with title "Title" \
              default answer "" \
              with icon caution \
              with hidden answer
        end tell
    """ % prompt

    p = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-e', script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read()

    g = re.match("text returned:(.*), button returned:.*", out)

    if not g:
        return "HO"
    return g.group(1)
    return out

print askpass('decription')
```

Comment: what is  `if 'yes/no' in prompt`  doing?  `return out` is unreachable and use check_output or communicate if you want output from subprocess.  Also why are you using a subprocess at all?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here for us to help you. What is the result of `out` after `out = p.stdout.read()`?

Comment: Is this really a Python question? It looks more like an AppleScript question. What does that `osascript` command do when you run it directly from the console, leaving Python out of it entirely? If *that* doesn't work, then you need to go debug that before you try wrapping it with Python.

Comment: out outputs nothing @colinbasnett

Comment: @Neb: put a `print(out)` statement after `out = p.stdout.read()` and you will see what is going wrong. Your search doesn't match your script's output.

Answer (score 1):

I tried here, and the returned text is switched.

You expect `text returned:(.*), button returned:.*`, but the AppleScript has returned in format `button returned:.*, text returned:(.*)`.

I suggest you use:

```
g = re.search(r'text returned:(\S*)', out)
```

Or something like this.